# Does `DOCTYPE` affect the use of HTML5 features like `postMessage` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to use the HTML5 `postMessage` feature to make communication between "host" and "iframe" possible. The problem is, the `DOCTYPE` of html in host page is not guaranteed(But iframe does).

So, can I use `postMessage` or any other HTML5 features in JavaScript even if the `DOCTYPE` is "HTML4" or "XHTML"?

I have tried 1) HTML4 DOCTYPE 2) XHTML DOCTYPE 3) without a DOCTYPE in the lastest Chrome and IE10. They all work. But I don't know whether they will work in other scenarios.

Comment: The only way to know for *sure* is to try, but to my knowledge, there is no browser that discriminates JavaScript feature support by DOCTYPE.

Comment: @MattPatenaude, trying (i.e., testing in a few environments) is not a way to know anything for sure.

Comment: I don't think to try is a way to know it for sure either. The mechanism within the browser may tell us the truth.. @MattPatenaude, @ Jukka K. Korpela

Comment: postMessage will work in all browsers since and including IE8, regardless of a specific, any, or even an erroneous doctype; if you can see html on the screen, you can use postMessage. further, no html5 feature is enabled or disabled by using an older doctype. old ie has it's own quirks that activate w/o a doctype, but they aren't html5 features.

Comment: @dandavis Your comment is useful for me, thanks :). If there're some tests or documentations supporting that will be more convincible.

Comment: seeing as how you said it all works, i shouldn't have to support anything, the burden is on demonstrating a flaw, which doesn't make since since we were beyond doctypes when HTML5 was adopted. the html5 doctype itself was discovered, not designed. that all said, ppk had the best info on quirks and browser features back when doctypes were big deals: http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/index.html if you have ie10, run it as 8 in all three modes and see what happens.

Comment: oh, and http://caniuse.com/x-doc-messaging says that postMessage works everywhere...

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela By "knowing for sure," I did mean knowing for sure for your particular application, in the particular use cases you choose to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer's earlier versions change certain JS behaviors in Quirks Mode. This changes availability of some interfaces such as `document.all`.

I don't know if there is a comprehensive list of this anywhere though.

Other browsers don't change JS behavior whether in Quirks Mode or not.

Comment: "Other browsers don't change JS behavior whether in Quirks Mode or not". Like so many things in HTML, that's almost but not quite true. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283890/what-is-the-difference-of-having-a-doctype-and-backcompat-vs-css1compat-mode/18298085#18298085 gives a summary of Quirks Mode changes in modern browsers including a couple of minor variations to behaviour in JS.

Comment: @Alochi I was referring to the availability of interfaces but thanks for the link, that is certainly useful info for the asker :)

Answer (score 0):

There is really no way to know. Currently, browsers do DOCTYPE sniffing that triggers Standards, Quirks, or some other mode, which mainly affects interpretation of CSS code, but also JavaScript (DOM) and HTML to some extent. Whether it is HTML5 DOCTYPE or HTML 4 DOCTYPE is not crucial; it is much more important whether an HTML 4 DOCTYPE exactly matches one of those that browsers recognize as triggering Standards mode. But the sniffing game is complicated, though, and some day the difference might matter.